# debian系システムにおいてlibapt(or libept)を使ってpackageの依存関係を取得するにはどうすればよいですか

Tags: c++, debian

[How to use libapt (or libept) in debian-like system to list packages and get their infos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341520/how-to-use-libapt-or-libept-in-debian-like-system-to-list-packages-and-get-the)

のページの回答にパッケージの一覧を表示するサンプルコードがありますが
依存関係の一覧を表示するコードがありません。

Synapticやlibaptのコードを追いかけたりしていますがわかりませんでした。
libapt-pkg-docをみても大した記述がなく当てになりませんでした。

依存関係を表示するためのサンプルがあればお教えください。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

apt のソースコード `apt/cmdline/apt-cache.cc` にある [DumpPackage 関数](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/debian/experimental/cmdline/apt-cache.cc#L202)がサンプルとしては丁度良いのではないでしょうか。これは `apt-cache showpkg` の実行本体に当たります。

関数の引数である `CmdL` は main 関数の `char *argv[]` と同等の変数(オブジェクト)です。内部で使用されている `CmdL.FileList + 1` は `argv + 1` に当たりますので、DumpPackage 関数を取り出して単一のプログラムにすることができます(初期化コードを追加する必要はありますが)。

ただ、私の方で使用している Ubuntu 15.04 では libapt-private 関連のインクルードファイルなどがインストールされないので、前述の github リポジトリから取得した apt パッケージをビルド、別ディレクトリにインストールして、そちらのライブラリなどを使う様にする必要がありました。